# Open android app from URL launches blank screen

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have an issue launching app from `URL` using intent filter. I had an activity made browsable by using `intent-filter` when i click the link my app shows in app chooser when i click on my app it shows blank screen, also my code in activity does not execute because, i write code for `Toast`  message but it never shows up.
i did try link in two formats given below

```
href="intent://www.example.com/gizmos#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.my.app;S.extra_string=name@domain.com;end"
```

and

```
href="http://www.example.com/gizmos"
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is manifest code

```
<activity
        android:name=".BrowseableActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:path="/gizmos" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is `Activity`

```
public class BrowseableActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    Toast.makeText(this,"called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it :) issue was with my activity i aded a new activity and add same filter for that it works fine.

before i was adding java class and then manually added activity in manifest it doesn't work.